# Magento My Account new page

Tags: magento, custom-pages

I want to add new page to my account section. I need to place an iframe with some custom logic in this page.

I have tried adding link in below section.

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>

        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>

    </reference>
```

but it generates 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this 
 <customer_account>        
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">           
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="modulename">
            <name>Tab Name</name>
            <path>path/index/index</path>
            <label>Tab Info</label>
        </action>      
    </reference>    
</customer_account>  
    <modulename_index_index>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">    
 <block type="blockname/blockname" name="blockname" template="file.phtml" />
        </reference>    
    </modulename_index_index>
```

Comment: Hello Sushil, Thanks for the answer, but can you please explain in which file i need to add this?

Comment: `customer.xml` of your current theme, and please select it as your answer if it helps you